# WeDriver FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

i am having issues in acquiring correct driver instance.
following is my setup

```
public class SeleniumBase{
    public static WebDriver  driver;
      public static void setUp(url,browser,port){
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      }
      public static void tearDown(){      
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();         
      }
    }

public class BuildTest extends SeleniumBase{

    @BeforeClass
        public static void seleniumSetup(){
        try{
            // read properties
            url = prop.getProp("baseUrl");
            browser = prop.getProp("browser");
            port = prop.getProp("port");
            }
            SeleniumBase.setUp(url,browser,port);
            waitForLoginPage();
            App.login();
        }
    @AfterClass
        public static void seleniumTearDown(){
            App.logOut();
            SeleniumBase.tearDown();
        }
}

@RunWith(Suite.class)
    @Suite.SuiteClasses(
            {                                               
                Test1.class,
                Test2.class
            })

public class SmokeSuite {


}
```

now, for Test1.class everything works fine but when Test2.class is invoked from the suite, new driver instance is created with the setUp method, but App.Login() throws error saying `"The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called"`

is anything going wrong in my setup/teardown..?

Comment: Where are you instantiating App? Also, do you have to use a static instance? I would recommend setting up and tearing down per class with the code at a class level. Perhaps using a base test class to stop duplication

Comment: I am not sure `seleniumSetup()` and `seleniumTearDown()` should be static methods.

Comment: You should create normal method instead of static method, also webdriver variable name should be without static

Comment: i have one suggestion for in Test1.class you are writing driver.quit() so replace this with driver.close(), it will works.

Comment: Don't use driver.close(), it will error if the browser has already been shut.  driver.quit() will close it if it hasn't been closed.  driver.close() is really designed to be used with multiple windows.

Comment: Also calling driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); and then driver.quit()  is a waste of time.  Once you quit the browser all the cookies will be destroyed because you will get a clean profile the next time you open it.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments on your question already mention, your `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods as well as your `WebDriver` instance are **`static`**. So once you call `driver.quit()`, your driver couldn't be used any more. A new driver needs to be acquired.

However, you do not use JUnit's `@Before` and `@After` annotations but rather `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`. So I guess you have multiple tests in your `Test2` class, the driver quits after the first one and is not reinitialized before the second test.

Better make `WebDriver`, `setUp()` and `tearDown` not static and use `@Before` and `@After` in your test-classes. Then your problems should go away.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `driver.quit();` you close all open browsers and quit the driver. However, your `driver` is not set to `null` but remains in the void between `WebDriver` instance to `null`.

Why does this matter? Because when you call `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` the constructor is "cheating" and hands you the old `WebDriver` instance, which considered viable because it doesn't see `null`, instead of initializing new instance.

Assigning `null` after calling quit should solve the problem.

```
public void tearDown() {
    driver.quit();
    driver = null;
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect! A constructor cannot _cheat_. The `new` operator **always** returns a new instance of the given class and the constructor will be called. See [the java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5) for details.